# Error installing shopify_theme command line tool

Tags: ruby, rubygems, shopify

I've been trying without much success to install [shopify_theme](https://github.com/Shopify/shopify_theme) a console tool for interacting with Shopify theme assets.

I've been trying to follow the usage instructions on the github project page, but have hit a wall:

Via my Terminal (OS X Mavericks) I enter:

```
gem install shopify_theme
```

I get back this error:

```
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::ImpossibleDependenciesError)
httparty-0.12.0 requires json (~> 1.8) but it conflicted:
Activated json-1.8.1 instead of (~> 1.5.4) via:
shopify_theme-0.0.12
```

I've tried without success to get around this by manually installing JSON, manually installing httpary, and manually installing other involved dependencies, but it makes no difference.

Please halp!

*EDIT:* I think I've found a solution:

After banging my head against the screen for 8 hours straight I discovered a solution to my dependency woes. In my case I was working on from a totally fresh install of OS X Mavericks (10.9).

Open up your terminal and perform the following:

1) Install the latest version of ruby via rvm. (http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ruby/how-to-install-ruby-on-a-mac/)

```
\curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable —rails —autolibs=enabled # Or, —ruby=1.9.3
```

2) Update rvm.

```
rvm get stable —auto-dotfiles
```

3) shopify_theme requires that you use ruby 1.9.

```
rvm install ruby-1.9.3-p448
rvm use 1.9
```

4) Move to your project root, we are going to install packages specifically for your working directory.

```
cd path/to/project/root/
```

5) To handle specific gem dependancies use Bundler. (http://bundler.io/)

```
gem install bundler
```

6) Create a Gemfile in working directory.

```
bundle init
```

7) Edit your Gemfile. Open it in your editor of choice. Replace it’s contents with this:

```
source “https://rubygems.org”

gem ‘shopify_theme’
gem ‘httparty’
```

8) Generate your Gemfile.lock and install your dependancies.

```
bundle install
```

9) Finally you can install shopify_theme.

```
gem install shopify_theme
```

This is what worked for me. If anyone recognizes unnecessary steps in here, I'd be interested to know.

Comment: In ubuntu it is enough to install ruby-dev to make the error mentioned above disappear.